# Why doesn't my implementation of AuthenticationProvider with Java Config work?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I tried to connect a custom AuthenticationProvider to the Spring Security configuration like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/signup", "/resources/**", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll();
    }

}
```

Here is my CustomAuthenticationProvider class:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired private UserService userService;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {

    String email = (String) auth.getPrincipal();
    String password = (String) auth.getCredentials();

    System.out.println("[CustomAuthenticationProvider] Authentication try [" + email +"]");

    User user = (User) userService.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("[CustomAuthenticationProvider] Authentication Failed!!! Reason: User is not exist: [" + email + "]");
    }

    if (user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("[CustomAuthenticationProvider] - Authentication Success!!!");

        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password, roles);
            result.setDetails(user);
            return result;
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("[CustomAuthenticationProvider] Authentication Failed!!! Reason: Wrong password");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

I opened the browser and connected to the url: "localhost:8080/login"
I can see the login page, and I input the id/pw.
After I click the "login" button, I expected to find some log output for `CustomAuthenticationProvider`.  But there is no log output.  This means my `CustomAuthenticationProvider` is not working.

I checked Google and stackoverflow, but I cannot find the resolution.

Before this, I used XML configuration like:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

That code works fine, but I am trying moving the code from XML to Java Configuration.

I am using Spring Boot ver 1.27.  Here is the relevant portion of my POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you enable logging on some Spring classes?  It may tell you what is happening to the requests.  I would imagine that it's something with your config and not the actual class since the XML config works.  `<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" />
 <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping" level="DEBUG" />
 <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" level="DEBUG" />
 <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation" level="DEBUG" />`

Comment: Could you tell me what XML file do you mean?

Comment: Most projects have a logging system for debug statements and the like.  You'll want to include a logging system like log4j or logback over slf4j.  They each have their respective XML files.  If you use the Java logging system, then it's logging.properties.